# Why ko.applyBindings does not do anything on UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have below HTML code and the javascript code. I am using Oracle JET tags in HTML and knockout js functions. There is no error displayed in the console, but I do not see any data, div remain empty. Expected result is a single select menu on UI. Please assist.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="SelectionWrapperDiv"> 
<oj-select-one id="MenuToSelect" value="{{val}}" style="max-width:20em" on-value-changed="[[valueChangedHandler]]" >

    <oj-option value="A">A</oj-option> 
    <oj-option value="A">B</oj-option> 
    <oj-option value="A">C</oj-option> 
    <oj-option value="A">D</oj-option> 
</oj-select-one>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function ValueModel() {
    this.val = ko.observable(CPQJS.getAttributeVal('ProfilesSelectedTEST')); 
    this.evtData = ko.observable(); 
     this.valueChangedHandler = function (event) { 
    this.evtData(event.detail); 
    var data = this.evtData(); 
       if (data) {  
         CPQJS.setAttributeVal('ProfilesSelectedTEST', data.value); 
        } 
    }.bind(this);
  } 
 $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ValueModel(), document.getElementById('SelectionWrapperDiv')); 
    
 });
```

**Also Included below file in Header of page:**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle Jet Tags so I'm not going to be much help with that side of things.  If this was a standard html select however, I would expect that there would be something like this present

`<select data-bind="options: evtData, value: val"></select>`

so that when knockout was applying the binding it would know what object properties it needs to bind to.